# Publish Teams app to Teams Store with variable messaging endpoint

Tags: microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams, teams-toolkit

We are ISV and our ERP system is used by many organizations on-prem and in the cloud. We are developing a conversational bot for Microsoft Teams based on the Bot Framework. The bot itself is integrated within the application server, and we would like to publish it to the Teams App Store. The problem is that there are many deployments of application servers with different URLs, and the bot messaging endpoint address is different for each app server deployment: on-prem customer or cloud pod.

Is there a way to publish a Teams bot app to Teams Store with the variable messaging endpoint?

I am aware that is possible to build the single-point proxy/dispatcher that will redirect requests based on tenantId, but that adds an extra point of failure and complicates maintenance and support.

Thanks

Comment: fyi App Store questions are off-topic here. See [Are developer-centric questions about application stores on topic for Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/272165)

Comment: I was redirected from Microsoft dev support to StackOverflow. In the response, they claim that StackOverflow is their official dev support channel: "Per the description you have shared, your query is related to the Microsoft Teams developer Team. Teams community of developers use Stack Overflow and Microsoft Q&A to connect with other developers to ideate, get clarifications, and submit queries"

Comment: Stack Overflow, however, is not an official Microsoft property, and has its own guidelines. Questions here have to be *programming questions*, which your question is not. They can certainly direct people here for programming questions, but the guidelines apply to all questions posted here.

Comment: "programming questions"? Programming is not just writing code in JS, Java, or C#. The answer to my question could easily be the option in the Teams bot manifest JSON file. Isn't that "programming"? I think your view of guidelines is too strict. I have been programming in many languages and frameworks for a few decades and this is a "programming" question.

Comment: Aside from this not being a programming question, you haven't provided any specifics, only a requirement. I suggest reading about creating a [mcve], as well as reading [Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question).  If you disagree with how this question is being moderated, feel free to post on [meta], but... as written, this question is off-topic.

Answer (score 0):

I've got the answer on Microsoft Q&E. Don't like it, but it is what it is:

*No, it is not possible to publish a Teams bot app to the Teams Store with a variable messaging endpoint. The messaging endpoint for a bot is the URL where your bot receives and sends messages, and it must be a fixed, valid, and publicly accessible HTTPS URL. When you submit your bot to the Teams Store, you must provide the messaging endpoint URL as part of the app submission process, and this URL cannot be changed dynamically. If you need to change the messaging endpoint for your bot, you will need to update the app manifest and resubmit the app to the Teams Store for approval.*